# Kentico - "Send email queue" scheduled task stuck

Tags: queue, scheduled-tasks, kentico

Our client can't received email and I have found the issue with the schedule task "Send email queue":
The task couldn't not stop before I disabled it.
When I enable again, it works fine, but I want to know exactly the problem to not sure it NOT stuck again

More detail: 
- Kentico: v10.0.50
- Event log: i dôn't see any log about the task

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to resolve that issue is to upgrade to a newer version. There are a list of things about a mile long which could cause it to hang. We've found the upgrade is most successful.

If you want to troubleshoot, check the following:

- to email is a valid email address
- from email address is a valid email
- smtp credentials are correct
- smtp provider doesn't have some limitation on sending
- the user accounts sending the emails has proper send permissions (common issue with Office 365)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on top of the answer from Brenden, make sure that the application is alive and it does not restart or stop if there are no requests coming in from the application.

This task should call to an instance of ThreadSender and since all actions are done asynchronously in separate thread, task itself will not log any errors. It will just jumpstart a ThreadSender thread and it should be running and processing queue. You can check if the thread is running in Debug application Worker Threads tab. Any errors related would be logged in event log with ThreadSender source.