# Kentico - “Send email queue” scheduled task not working Kentico 10.0.50 on Azure

Tags: azure, kentico

I have a problem with the kentico site on Azure.

I didn't send the email queuse. I figured out that the Scheduled Task didn't run in a long time.

I fixed it by restarting the Scheduled task and it works but this happens again.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Is this "Send queued emails" enabled and scheduled to be run for every minute (but don't run actually)? Or has it become disabled with no reason? Is there anything in the Event Log?

Comment: My solution is to build a custom task for sending queue email and it works for me on this Kentico Version

Comment: I was wrong, bc the Scheduler is Failed so that I can't make the custom schedule run to Send Queued Emails. 
Finally, I figured out that I can write a custom code to trigger once the Scheduler is  Failed. So that I can restart the schedule tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably its a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078755/kentico-send-email-queue-scheduled-task-stuck).

Try to run the email queue task in separate thread and check it's status in the debug application.

Answer (score 0):

The same question was submitted on [DevNet](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/kentico-send-email-queue-scheduled-task-not-working-kentico-10-0-50-on-azure) where other people replied as well. There is no need to post the same question here and on DevNet as both discussions are connected.